# HERE Flutter SDK Issue - Method not found

Tags: android, sdk

I develop on the flutter framework, when I install the here sdk and make the necessary settings.

I run the example program the following error is displayed on the debugging console, would you have a solution to this problem?

```
plugins/here_sdk/lib/src/builtin_types__conversion.dart:82:23: Error: Method not found: 'Utf8.toUtf8'.
  final cValue = Utf8.toUtf8(value);
                      ^^^^^^
plugins/here_sdk/lib/src/builtin_types__conversion.dart:84:3: Error: Method not found: 'free'.
  free(cValue);
  ^^^^
plugins/here_sdk/lib/src/builtin_types__conversion.dart:88:53: Error: Method not found: 'Utf8.fromUtf8'.
String String_fromFfi(Pointer<Void> handle) => Utf8.fromUtf8(_String_get_value(handle));
                                                    ^^^^^^^^
plugins/here_sdk/lib/src/builtin_types__conversion.dart:120:30: Error: Method not found: 'Utf8.toUtf8'.
  final cLanguageCode = Utf8.toUtf8(locale.languageCode);
                             ^^^^^^
plugins/here_sdk/lib/src/builtin_types__conversion.dart:122:39: Error: Method not found: 'Utf8.toUtf8'.
    locale.countryCode != null ? Utf8.toUtf8(locale.countryCode) : Pointer<Utf8>.fromAddress(0);
                                      ^^^^^^
plugins/here_sdk/lib/src/builtin_types__conversion.dart:124:38: Error: Method not found: 'Utf8.toUtf8'.
    locale.scriptCode != null ? Utf8.toUtf8(locale.scriptCode) : Pointer<Utf8>.fromAddress(0);
                                     ^^^^^^
plugins/here_sdk/lib/src/builtin_types__conversion.dart:125:29: Error: Method not found: 'Utf8.toUtf8'.
  final cLanguageTag = Utf8.toUtf8(locale.toLanguageTag());
                            ^^^^^^
plugins/here_sdk/lib/src/builtin_types__conversion.dart:129:3: Error: Method not found: 'free'.
  free(cLanguageCode);
  ^^^^
plugins/here_sdk/lib/src/builtin_types__conversion.dart:130:34: Error: Method not found: 'free'.
  if (cCountryCode.address != 0) free(cCountryCode);
                                 ^^^^
plugins/here_sdk/lib/src/builtin_types__conversion.dart:131:33: Error: Method not found: 'free'.
  if (cScriptCode.address != 0) free(cScriptCode);
                                ^^^^
lugins/here_sdk/lib/src/builtin_types__conversion.dart:132:3: Error: Method not found: 'free'.
  free(cLanguageTag);
  ^^^^
plugins/here_sdk/lib/src/builtin_types__conversion.dart:141:30: Error: Method not found: 'Utf8.fromUtf8'.
    return Locale.parse(Utf8.fromUtf8(languageTagCstring));
                             ^^^^^^^^
plugins/here_sdk/lib/src/builtin_types__conversion.dart:149:59: Error: Method not found: 'Utf8.fromUtf8'.
    languageCode: languageCodeCstring.address != 0 ? Utf8.fromUtf8(languageCodeCstring) : null,
                                                          ^^^^^^^^
plugins/here_sdk/lib/src/builtin_types__conversion.dart:150:57: Error: Method not found: 'Utf8.fromUtf8'.
    countryCode: countryCodeCstring.address != 0 ? Utf8.fromUtf8(countryCodeCstring) : null,
                                                        ^^^^^^^^
plugins/here_sdk/lib/src/builtin_types__conversion.dart:151:55: Error: Method not found: 'Utf8.fromUtf8'.
    scriptCode: scriptCodeCstring.address != 0 ? Utf8.fromUtf8(scriptCodeCstring) : null
                                                      ^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Dev\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Dev\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 30s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding to pubspec.yaml:

```
ffi: ^0.1.3
```

This should not be necessary with upcoming versions of SDK, but it does the job until then.